# Append multiple 1D arrays to an "empty" 2D array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, append

Consinder the following example:

```
# z = empty object, if possible empty 2D-array
  N = 2

for i in range(N):
    l = i * array([2,2,2])
    # z.function(l)
```

Is there a function or a way to append multiple 1D-arrays to an empty object z and convert it into an 2D array

In my case N = 10**5 and the l-arrays are computed.

In the end i want a 2D array so i can apply slice operations (extract columns,rows,..)

Comment: You can do this with list comprehension, even better if you are using numpy, just do some matrix products

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
import numpy

x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])

print(numpy.array([i*x for i in range(2)]))
```

Output is:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Numpy library, you can do it with the following code:

```
    import numpy as np


    x = np.array([1,2,3]) 

    #making an empty array with the shape and data type used in x
    y = np.zeros(shape=x.shape,dtype=x.dtype) 

    #connecting two 1d arrays to a 2d one
    z = np.concatenate((y,x)) #joining 

    print(z)
```

this will connect them to :

```
   z= [[0, 0, 0],[1, 2, 3]]
```